# Example of danger of limit property

Tags: calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

I know that **if** both of the limits
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to a} g(x)
$$
exist (so they are both equal to real numbers), then
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(x) + g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x)  + \lim_{x\to a} g(x) 
$$
One could also use the difference or the product instead of the sum. Implied in this is that the limit of the sum of the two functions exist. It is easy to see that the converse of this is not true. That is, the limit of the sum may exist without the limits of the two functions exist.

I can also see how this can be extended to include the cases where, say, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$ (so it doesn't exist) and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exists (if we understand that $\infty + b = \infty$ for all $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

I see also that people will use this property without first arguing that the two limits exist. For example
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} x + x^2 = \lim_{x\to 1} x + \lim_{x\to 1} x^2 = 1 + 1 = 1
$$
That is, one possibly ought to first state that $\lim_{x\to 1} x$ and $\lim_{x\to 1} x^2$ both exist before using the rule. But all the examples that I have seen of limits, this is never a problem. That is, I don't remember ever seeing a computation of a limit where one uses the rule assume that the two limits exist, but where one of the limits to not in fact exist, but one ends up with an (incorrect) answer.

**Finally, here is my question: What is an example of a limit where one falsely uses the rule
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(x) + g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x)  + \lim_{x\to a} g(x) 
$$**

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-a}$ and $g(x)=-\frac{1}{x-a}$

Comment: @Blue: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. In this case the sum of the limits would exist?

Comment: @JohnDoe In Blue's example, the sum of $f$ and $g$ is just $0$. So yes, $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f+g=0$.

Comment: (Taking $a=0$ for simplicity ...) Neither $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}$ nor $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)$ exist, so "the sum of the limits" does not exist. On the other hand, 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}+\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to0}0=0$$ so "the limit of the sum" *does* exist. Is this not the issue you're getting at?

Comment: @Blue I think the inclusion of $a$ is unnecessary in the example, and complicates it a bit. Just $f(x)=-g(x)=\frac1x$ should suffice, with $\lim\limits_{x\to0}$.

Comment: @DonThousand: Good point. I've updated my comment.

Comment: I don't think the comments above address the question (as per my interpretation). In fact, the point is that you "can actually always" go from $\lim(f + g)$ to $\lim(f)+\lim(g)$ in a "reasonable" way. Note that in the questions like $\lim x^2 + x$, you can just split it and then note along the way that the individual limits do exist. So, even though strictly speaking one must do the check before the splitting, it is okay to not do that. The only caveat is that just because you split and note that the individual limits don't exist, you can't conclude that the original limit didn't exist either.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani That's incorrect. Blue's example disproves this.

Comment: @DonThousand: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I read can't as can. I need some coffee.

Comment: What has higher priority, $\lim$ or $+$? If $\lim$ has the higher precedence (this is what I beliefe), then the left side means $(\lim f)+ g$, so you should better write $\lim(f+g)$. If $+$ has the higher precedence than the meaning of the right side is $\lim (f+\lim g)$ and you should better write $(\lim f)+\lim g$. So you should use parenthesis either on the right or on the left side of our equation.

Comment: A bounty is a nice thing. But I think it would be more useful to give feedback to to the answers and comments. How should the users here know why the answers already given, before the bounty  was offered or after it was offered, are not sufficient? At least I don't feel like writing an answer when the questioner ignores me.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem says if the limits of f(x) and g(x) exist, then the limit of $f(x)+g(x)$ exist and it is equal to the sum of limits.

It does not say anything about the case where limits of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ do not exist.

Note that $f(x)+g(x)$ is by itself a function and its limit does not necessarily depend on the limit of $f(x)$ or $g(x).$

For example $$\frac {1}{x} + \frac {-1}{x} =0=x+(-x)$$
Where in one case limits do exist and in another case they do not exist but in both cases the limit of the sum does exist.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: the theorem states that if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist (in $\mathbb R$), then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+g(x)$ exists, and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$. The converse of this theorem is not true: in other words, if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+g(x)$ exists, then it is not necessarily the case that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist. For example,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\left(-\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)
$$
exists and equals $0$, but both $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(1/x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0}-\sin(1/x)$ do not exist. Another natural question is whether it is possible for $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+g(x)$ exist, given that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ does *not* exist. The answer is no. Can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think that I can show you such an example.

One of my students found $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^2+3x+4}{(x+2)(x^2+2)}$ as follows :
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^2+3x+4}{(x+2)(x^2+2)}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{x+1}{x^2+2}\bigg)
\\\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x+2}+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+1}{x^2+2}
\\\\&=0+0
\\\\&=0\end{align}$$
and this is correct.

Then, the student tried to find $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-2x^3+2x^2}{(x+2)(x^2+2)}$ as follows :
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-2x^3+2x^2}{(x+2)(x^2+2)}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{x^2}{x+2}+\frac{-x^3}{x^2+2}\bigg)
\\\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x+2}+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-x^3}{x^2+2}
\\\\&=(+\infty) +(-\infty)\end{align}$$
where the student falsely used the rule
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(x) + g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x)  + \lim_{x\to a} g(x) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let me add a couple of more examples.

---

$$f(x)=\csc x,\quad g(x)=-\cot x$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(f(x)+g(x)\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\tan \frac x2=0$$
but, either $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to0}g(x)$ doesn't exist.

---

$$f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor,\quad g(x)=\lfloor -x\rfloor$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(f(x)+g(x)\right)=-1$$
but, either $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to0}g(x)$ doesn't exist.